# BIRT viewer - IOException: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: birt

I'm getting the stacktrace below printed to my log/console.  I'm using Tomcat 6.0 and BIRT 2.6.2.  It's not stopping the viewer from displaying reports, but it is taking up precious space in the log.

I found someone having a similar problem [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/663982/), but there's no clear indication as to what the resolution was.  Like the poster in that link, I am in the middle of upgrading to a new version of BIRT (2.6.2).

Let me know if you need any more information about my setup.  I'm fairly new to BIRT.  *Any* help is welcome, even if you can suggest a place to look.

```
java.io.IOException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.util.SAXDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory.createDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.util.SvgFile.transSvgToArray(SvgFile.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.util.SvgFile.transSvgToArray(SvgFile.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.handleStyleImage(HTMLReportEmitter.java:3423)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.AttributeBuilder.buildBackground(AttributeBuilder.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLVisionOptimize.buildStyle(HTMLVisionOptimize.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.outputCSSStyles(HTMLReportEmitter.java:906)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.html.HTMLReportEmitter.start(HTMLReportEmitter.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.emitter.CompositeContentEmitter.start(CompositeContentEmitter.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:928)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunAndRenderActionHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.layout.EngineFragment.doService(EngineFragment.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.presentation.aggregation.AbstractBaseFragment.service(AbstractBaseFragment.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtEngineServlet.__doGet(BirtEngineServlet.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BaseReportEngineServlet.doGet(BaseReportEngineServlet.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BaseReportEngineServlet.doPost(BaseReportEngineServlet.java:224)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BaseReportEngineServlet.service(BaseReportEngineServlet.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from entering the background image property in the style of a report design.

In CSS, the backgroundImage property requires `url('path/to/image.jpg')`.

```
body {
    background-image:url('path/to/image.jpg');
}
```

However BIRT appears to be rendering the following for the style:

```
body {
    background-image:'path/to/image.jpg';
}
```

In order to get around this I entered the following in the initialize script for every report design that uses the backgroundImage style:

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findStyle("blueresultsetheaderrow").backgroundImage = "url('images/BlueSortTitleBar.gif')";
```

I suspect that this is a bug, so I logged [this one](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365364).